# php regex to match string in pipe delimited text

Tags: php, regex, string, pipe, csv

This is an example line in the document I am processing:

```
    2011-08-08|M|Misc Info|6PM|Away vs. First Words, Second String, Third|Other Info
```

I would like to get everything between "Away vs." and the next "|"

Comment: Will the document always be in a similar format? Also, how will missing data be handled in this format?

Comment: What regex were you using so far? What's your code so far? Into which problem did you run? Or are you just asking for code?

Comment: That looks pipe-separated, not pipe-delimited.  Which did you mean? `|a|b|c|` has three three fields if pipe-delimited and five fields if pipe separated.

Answer (score 1):

Just use php's explode function to make an array.

```
$str = "2011-08-08|M|Misc Info|6PM|Away vs. First Words, Second String, Third|Other Info";
$arr = explode($str, '|');


$parts = $arr[4];
$newArr = explode($parts, ',');
```

Comment: Explode may not do well if he is processing large chunks of data. Also, this would give him several unnecessary arrays - he only needs a string extracted from his format.

Answer (score 1):

```
$string = '2011-08-08|M|Misc Info|6PM|Away vs. First Words, Second String, Third|Other Info';
$parts = explode('|', $string);
echo $parts[4]; // This is what you are looking for.
```

I don't see why you would use regexes here.

If you are using PHP 5.3 there's another solution:

```
$parts = str_getcsv($string, '|');
echo $parts[4]; // This should be the part you're looking for
```

[`str_getcsv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) also understands enclosed strings, making it more robust.

Comment: I had tried something that did `strpos()` until it reached the correct pipe, but a test showed that it was considerably slower than this solution. +1.